# Firefox Session Restore causes bug in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox

After a Firefox crash, the browser's restore functionality seems to be causing an incorrect AngularJS binding.

**EDIT:**
I am updating the title to reflect what may be closer to the actual problem. I just discovered the Session Store in Firefox. After I kill the browser in Step 4 below, I can open recovery.js from my Firefox profile and see the details of Case A. I have confirmed that this is where the data is coming from in Step 6 by changing a value in the .js file directly before reopening Firefox.

---

I've written a web application with AngularJS that allows my users to manage their legal case load. I have a very strange bug in Firefox (currently using 36.0.1) that I can reproduce consistently.

Summary: A user saves one case and moves to work on another, when their browser or computer crashes. When they reopen Firefox, the details for their previous case have now been associated with the latest one. Upon closer inspection, I can see that the correct case details are shown for a split second when the browser reloads, but then replaced with the incorrect details.

Walkthrough:

1. The user opens Case A, edits some data, and saves.

   - The URL is https://url/cases/A
   - `$scope.case` is set to Case A from a web service call, updated, and posted to the web service
2. The user clicks back to their list of pending cases

   - The URL is https://url/cases
   - `$scope.case = {}`
3. The user opens Case B, may or may not edit data, but does not save

   - The URL is https://url/cases/B
   - `$scope.case` is set to Case B from a web service call
4. The browser crashes (reproduced by killing the task)
5. The user reopens the browser and Case B is reloaded

   - The URL is https://url/cases/B
   - `$scope.case` is set to Case B but no web service call has taken place
6. After a fraction of a second, the fields switch to display Case A

   - The URL is still https://url/cases/B
   - `$scope.case` is set to Case A but no web service call has taken place
7. If the user saves the page, Case B is overwritten with Case A's information

   - The URL is still https://url/cases/B
   - Web service call is passed with Case A's data but Case B's ID

Notes:

- I cannot reproduce this in Chrome or IE
- A case details page is bound to `$scope.case`
- If I place an alert before `$scope.init`, the problem does not happen.
- I have written console logs at each place where my javascript updates `$scope.case`, but do not see where the switch to Case A happens.
- I can still reproduce the problem if I clear the browser cache, cookies, and form data after step 3 above

This is very bizarre. Any ideas about what could be going on here, or suggestions on where to look next?

Thanks!